# Is there a verb for replacing placeholder values with actual values in a template?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, programming

Is there a verb for replacing placeholder values with actual values in a template?

For example:

The verb for transforming *"Hello FirstName LastName"* to *"Hello John Smith"*.

Comment: One possibility is to say you [***populate** the template*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22populate+the+template%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You might consider converting this to an answer, especially given that neither of the alternatives has managed to garner a positive balance.  While I personally prefer *instantiate* conceptually, I think *populate* is the more common and better understood term for this particular usage.

Comment: @Chris: Given your profile says you've got a background in programming (as have I), I'm surprised you prefer *instantiate*  for OP's context. I'd see that as what happens when you create an *instance* of a template class (through an implicit or explicit call to its "new" constructor). In most cases no "value replacement" would take place until some later point when you call a method giving it a data source containing the values to be replaced - which method I would be likely to call *populate()*, rather than *instantiate()*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've already covered my reasoning *ad nauseam* in the comments to that answer.  However, *populate* is probably a better choice --one I would upvote if you had made it an actual answer.

Comment: @Chris: Sorry - I should have clicked on *Show more comments* below. To be honest, I never really became expert in using template classes (having developed my own idiosyncratic techniques long before it was even *practical* to implement such things in most programming contexts). So I can't claim any special knowledge re the IT context, and it's not 100% certain OP is specifically focused on that context anyway. But your point is well made, so given the current state of the votes I'll do as you suggest.

Comment: "Binding" is sometimes used to mean assigning values to symbols.

Comment: In computing we call that "(string) interpolation".

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is you [***populate*** the template](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22populate%20the%20template%22) (that's over 1000 written instances in Google Books).

Note that this use of *populate* is a bit "geeky", and thus likely to be restricted to *software* contexts. For more general contexts, it's worth noting that Google Books has nearly 9 times more instances of [***fill in*** the template](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fill%20in%20the%20template%22).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use *substituted*. I derive this from @deadrat's comments above - "The OP's situation seems to call for 'parameter substitution.'"

[Meaning](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=substituted)

> use or add in place of/replace

Google

In your case,

> The placeholders, *firstName* and *lastName* were **substituted** with the actual values "John" and "Smith" respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The verb is

> to instantiate

meaning to represent something by an instance. The act of instantiating is an [instantiation](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/instantiation):

> the representation of (an abstraction) by a concrete example (logic)

or

> the process of deriving an individual statement from a general one by
>   replacing the variable with a name or other referring expression

Comment: If the context is programming, then *instantiation* refers to the creation of an object according to a particular defined type.  The OP's situation seems to call for "parameter substitution."

Comment: The entry  expected from the user  is something that fits the type  "Hello FirstName LastName" .  Hello firstname is an abstraction of the type of values expected and the definition fits exactly "the representation of (an abstraction) by a concrete example". It's not a programming question as such. I mean the form could a piece of paper.

Comment: "Hello FirstName LastName" isn't a type in the context of programming.  If the question isn't related to programming, but to filling out paper forms with pencils, then *instantiation* is even less apt.

Comment: @deadrat I disagree.  Even by analogy to programming, *instantiation* is entirely correct and apt.  You are taking a general type (the template) and creating a specific *instance* of it.  That's exactly why we use the term in programming.

Comment: @ChrisSunami Look, I don't want to turn into That Internet Guy Who Has to Have the Last Word On Everything (and I don't know who "we" is here), but in programming, templates aren't lists of types; they're lists of names.  *Instantiation* is a term of art for making an object out of a class.  I'm done here except to note that I am not a downvoter.

Comment: @deadrat I'm also a professional programmer, I'm well aware of the term's technical use.  However, the point is that the term [predates](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/instantiation) modern programming. The reason we use it in programming is because of its original meaning.  Just because a word gains a specialized usage in a field doesn't mean it loses its original meaning.

Comment: @deadrat also parameter substitution seems  wrong. to substitute means to replace something by something similar, so for example  replacing the parameter "lenght" by "width" or "name" by "surname". Giving a value to a parameter is not substitution.

Comment: @ChrisSunami It seems to me that instantiation is indeed the correct word for taking a template and creating a specific instance of it. However that is not what the OP asked- their question was much more specialised than that and is self-evidently about a term for replacement of 'boilerplate' or 'placeholder' text within fields. In order to commence that activity the template must *already* have been instantiated surely?

Answer (score 0):

When referring to a template as a whole:

"Populate the template"
"Fill in the template"

Here, the word 'template' should provide some context about there being placeholders that are being replaced.

However, if the verb is used without the word template in the context, it is not as clear that only specific placeholder part is being replaced:

"Populate first name"
"Fill in first name"

In such a case, the word 'emplace' might be better:
"Emplace first name"

Or maybe 'embed'?